# VBA hiding multiple columns in excel. Else without IF

Tags: vba, excel

I found some code online that worked for a single column but needed to hide multiple columns so I edited it a bit. I keep gettingan Else without IF error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    If Range("B3").Value = 0 Then

        For i = 0 To 144
        Columns("D" + i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        i = i + 4

    Else
        For i = 0 To 144
        Columns("D" + i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        i = i + 4

    End If

End Sub
```

Where might I be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: So you didn't like the look of `Next` and deleted it from the code?

Comment: No sure what you mean? the code I found was from https://excel.tips.net/T003283_Hiding_Columns_Based_on_a_Cell_Value.html and didnt have next. I've never worked with VBA before so I didnt know about "Next"

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this instead and let me know what happens, we can improve on this if needed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long


For i = 0 To 144
    If Range("B" & i + 1).Value = vbNullString Then
        Range("D" & i + 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        i = i + 4
    Else
        Range("D" & i + 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        i = i + 4

    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Now you are checking `If Range("B3").Value = 0` a lot of times even though it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't attempted it yet, but how would I increment the column that needs to be hidden. It looks like i increases, but where in the code would that translate to the column that needs to be hidden also incrementing. Sorry, I'm just trying to follow along.

Comment: Sorry! I understand your question now. I will update the answer when I get home !

Comment: here you go :) HTH